# Exclusive end in Scala's Range class

Tags: scala, range

According to the [Scala documentation](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Range) for the method `Range.end`, it returns "the exclusive end of the range." So why does it return the same value for both the `to` and the `until` notations? For example:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM, Java 1.7.0).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> (1 to 10).end
res0: Int = 10

scala> (1 until 10).end
res1: Int = 10
```

Shouldn't `res0 == 11`?

Comment: [`RichInt.to`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/runtime/RichInt.html) doesn't result in a mere `Range`, it results in an [`Inclusive`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Range$$Inclusive.html).

Comment: I've never heard of the `end` before, but if you want the last element, use `last`. Scala's documentation sometimes isn't the best.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`to` and `until` result in related but different `Range` classes: `Range.Inclusive` and `Range`, respectively; `Range.Inclusive IS-A Range`.

- `isInclusive` will distinguish between the two class types.
- `end`, or the upper bound, is interpreted in the context of the range being exclusive or inclusive.  The upper bound is the second number provided in the range specification, which was `10` in both of the sample cases in the original question.  And yes, this "upper bound" may be less than the "lower bound", if the range goes from high to low (i.e. `1 until -10`).
- `last` will return the last value in the range, which may be what you were trying to obtain from `end`.